# ListView with header inside a horizontal scroll

Tags: android, listview, horizontal-scrolling

I have a `ListView` that I load data into it from a data table with about 10 columns, so I need the user to be able to scroll horizontally to see all the data.  Now I want to put Columns on top of the `ListView`, but inside the Horizontal Scroll.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to put the `TextBoxes` on top of the `ListView`, but inside the Horizontal scroll.  It always push `ListBox` in the same level at the `TextBoxes`.  It is even possible to do this?

My XML code is below:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="527dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/code"
            android:layout_width="110sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/lChangedTime"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/manufacturer"
            android:layout_width="70sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="manufacturer"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="200sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/manufacturer"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/lCustomerName"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/visc40"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="visc40"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/visc100"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/visc40"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="visc100"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you need to nest your text views in another layout.

let me show you what I mean

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id = "@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:layout_below = "@+id/imageView2">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "527dp"
            android:orientation = "vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:orientation = "horizontal">

            <TextView
                    android:id = "@+id/code"
                    android:layout_width = "110sp"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft = "0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart = "1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"
                    android:maxLines = "1"
                    android:text = "@string/lChangedTime"
                    android:textAppearance = "?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize = "17sp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id = "@+id/manufacturer"
                    android:layout_width = "70sp"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft = "11dp"
                    android:maxLines = "1"
                    android:text = "manufacturer"
                    android:textAppearance = "?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize = "17sp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id = "@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width = "200sp"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft = "11dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf = "@+id/manufacturer"
                    android:maxLines = "1"
                    android:text = "@string/lCustomerName"
                    android:textAppearance = "?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize = "20sp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id = "@+id/visc40"
                    android:layout_width = "50sp"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft = "11dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf = "@+id/name"
                    android:maxLines = "1"
                    android:text = "visc40"
                    android:textAppearance = "?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize = "17sp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id = "@+id/visc100"
                    android:layout_width = "50sp"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft = "11dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf = "@+id/visc40"
                    android:maxLines = "1"
                    android:text = "visc100"
                    android:textAppearance = "?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize = "17sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
                android:id = "@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop = "50sp"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:headerDividersEnabled = "true">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```