# Android scrollView cant scroll horizontal

Tags: android, scrollview

i have this main.xml for the listview with header.

what i would like to do that it should be able to scroll horizontal too with the header too.

can you help me to correct it?

Thank you!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Header -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff347c12" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="ID"
        android:width="30dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Property"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Sensor"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Sensor_type"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Unit"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Valid"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Field_device"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Magnitude"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Accuracy"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Store_data_unit"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Store_data_min"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Store_data_max"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Offset"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Com_port"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Com_parameters"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Timeout"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Field_device_address"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Modbus_register"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Communication_protocoll"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Term_char"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Request"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Data_bit_width"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Data_type"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item23"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Formula"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item24"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Variables"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Constanses"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item26"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Category"
        android:width="100dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item27"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="Sensor_description"
        android:width="100dip" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- List Divider -->

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- ListView (grid_items) -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it inside HorizontalScrollView as -

```
<HorizontalScrollView ...........>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView...................
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: but than it not moves the header...the textviews upper

Comment: Then put those header parts also inside the <HorizontalScrollView>. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701824/listview-with-header-inside-a-horizontal-scroll.

Comment: okay but than i get a problem that horizontalScrollView can only host one direct child

Comment: @David then put childs into LinearLayout

Comment: okay, but can you please post it how should it look like? thank you!